# Is there a way to know the max size of Azure DevOps Project Repo?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know if there is a maximum size allocated to Azure DevOps Project repo. I would like to understand how much file size an Azure DevOps Repo can support.

Comment: Hi @Anand Pangare For git limits ,you can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/limits?view=azure-devops)  If Mary's answer is helpful ,you can consider to  [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum size for the repo, but the recommandation is to not have more than 10GB. But you can have more if you want, there is not hard limit.

If you try to upload large files (more than 5GB) some files will fail to upload, for that you need to use another tool, like  Git-LFS : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops